# Api giving same results (New York Times)

Tags: javascript, html, api

This is the JavaScript Program

```
        var api = 'https://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?q=';
var Topic;
var apiKey = '&api-key=****';

function setup() {

  input = document.getElementById('topic').value;

}

function ArticleAsk(){

    var url = api + input.value() + apiKey;
    loadJSON(url, gotData);

}

function gotData(data){
    var articles = data.response.docs;

    for(var i = 0;i < articles.length; i++){
        createP(articles[i].snippet);
    }
}
```

This is HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>8.6_p5.js_api_query_user_input</title>
    <script src="libraries/p5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="libraries/p5.dom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="libraries/p5.sound.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="myScript2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

   <!--<script src="skect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>!-->
    <!-- <script src="myScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>!-->
    <style> body {padding: 0; margin: 0;} canvas {vertical-align: top;} </style>
  </head>
  <body>

   <p>
      Topic: <input id ="topic" value="New"></input>
      <br/>
      <button onclick="ArticleAsk()" id="submit">submit</button>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now the problem is that every time I go to a new topic it still gives me the same TOPIC "NEW" by default and sometimes its "value is not defined" although its the prebuilt method.

Comment: var url = api + input + apiKey;

Comment: 1/. you haven't run `setup` function. 2/. `input` is not a global variable 3/. if something wrong, `input` will refer to the value of `topic`, no need to call `value()` method again...

Comment: Thanks for this free API key, btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By writing `input = document.getElementById('topic').value` , `input` is already an element's value (a string). Then you call `input.value()` which is undefined. Try this way :

```
var input = document.getElementById('topic')

function ArticleAsk(){
    var url = api + input.value + apiKey;
    loadJSON(url, gotData);
}
```

Comment: Because you wrote `input = document.getElementById('topic').value;`. Notice the `.value` at the end.

Comment: Thanks Man!!! its Workin... But i did not understand the concept isnt vaue a method hence it needs to be called with ()... Plz explain and thanks again :)

Comment: The solution may be true, but the explanation is very wrong. `input` is `undefined` until you run `setup` function.

Comment: @Alan this is why I removed the `setup` function from my solution. It's useless and uncalled anyway.